# is it possible to extract images from iframe video?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have iframe tag which is running live streamings. My question is , is there any way to extract frame from iframe video? 
here is the tag:

```
<iframe id="video" width="100%" height="419" src="http://videoplayer.vodobox.com/vodobox_player.php?vid=http://109.123.70.72:1935/live/ptvsports/samitv.m3u8&img=&play=?" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is it possible to get image or screenshot of particular frame?

Comment: What do you mean by "to extract frame from iframe video"?
Also - Have you considered using the `<video>` tag?

Comment: yea i tried but i cannot use link http://videoplayer.vodobox.com/vodobox_player.php?vid=http://109.123.70.72:1935/live/ptvsports/samitv.m3u8&img=&play=? inside <video> but in iframe i can run but thing is i am trying to extract frame from running video.

Comment: u cant test in html and u will understand that there is live stream running and my question is is it possible to extract frames/images from running video?

Comment: Have you tried to pause the video and take a screen capture?

Comment: yes tried but not taking any screenshot. i am struggling in  it. And i have to use iframe bcz not all browser supports hls stream. I am using m3u8 as url.